# HTML checkbox tick/untick with PHP code

Tags: php, html, checkbox, config

Everyone, hello!

I'm trying to tick/untick a HTML checkbox with help from my PHP code.

The option if a checkbox has to be ticked or unticked I get from a config.ini file, which looks like this:

**config.ini**

```
[com]
p_ip = x.x.x.x.
p_port = xxx
p_username = xxx
p_password = xxx

[trigger]
string1_enable = no
string2_enable = yes
string3_enable = no
```

And I've activated the config.ini file in my index.php file as such:

**index.php**

```
<?php $ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); ?>
```

Now, as far as the HTML is concerned, I've tried this:

```
<td><li><input type="checkbox" class="categories-checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2"<?php if ($ini['string2_enable']=="yes") echo 'checked="yes"';?>><label for="chk2">Enable</label></li></td>
```

It doesn't throw an error, but it certainly won't enable. However, a simple:

```
<?php $ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); ?> 
<?php echo $ini['string2_enable']; ?>
```

yields a yes on my PHP page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does the `checked='yes'` show up in the generated html? If not, then make **SURE** that what's coming out of the ini parse is really just the three letters `y`, `e`, `s`, and doesn't contain extra stuff, like spaces or line breaks or whatever. e.g. `var_dump($ini)` and see what actually parsed out of there.

Comment: I would use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` in this case, to ensure what @MarcB is saying.

Comment: you're right... A var_dump() revealed it comes up as: ["string2_enable"]=> string(0) "". How is this possible? It's clearly saves as "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String values "true", "on" and "yes" are converted to TRUE. "false", "off", "no" and "none" are considered FALSE.

### Problem

The value of your `$ini['string2_enable']` is converted to `boolean (true)` so your if case will fail as it's not equal to `yes` anymore.

### Solution 1

So you have to replace your if case with this:

```
if($ini['string2_enable'])
```

### Solution 2

If for some reason you want to keep your `yes` value when parsing, you could add a `INI_SCANNER_RAW` flag to your function:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

With this option, your if case will now work properly.

### Source

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><li><input type="checkbox" class="categories-checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2"<?php if ($ini['string2_enable']=="yes") echo 'checked=true';?>><label for="chk2">Enable</label></li></td>
```

Notice "checked=true".  Just "checked" would also work.